# java double input panel

Tags: java, swing, input, popup, joptionpane

I have the following code:

```
String firstName;
firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("First Name");

String familyName;
familyName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Family Name");
```

With this code you will have 2 boxes popping up to fill in your name. However, I would like to know if there is a way of putting those two input boxes both on one popup.

Comment: I don't think you can, but you can make a new Frame with the two input in it and a button to validate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a panel containing two text fields and then just add the panel to the dialog :

```
  JPanel p = new JPanel();
  JTextField familyName = new JTextField(10);
  JTextField firstName = new JTextField(10);

  p.add(new JLabel("Family name :"));
  p.add(familyName);
  p.add(new JLabel("First name : "));
  p.add(firstName);

  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, p, "Family and first name : ", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Here's what it looks like :

[image]

Comment: This is a very good solution as well. The advantage of this approach is if you have a lot of design elements you want to add, or if you want to have greater control over the layout panels are the way to go.You can add multiple panels to a JFrame and use other layout helpers like grid or card layout from there.

Answer (score 4):

Add both of these JOptionPanel boxes to a single JFrame.

This way both of the input boxes will be on the same window.

JFrame frame = new JFrame.add(JOptionPanel);

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't do this using JOptionPane library. you can write your own class using java.swing package that provide multiple input on single popup.